# Simple Injector - register HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-core, simple-injector

I have been having issues registering HttpClient in my project. How can I do this?. I injected HttpClient in multiple classes and I need to register it to work for the multiple constructors.

Answer (score 1):

It will have error for using `container.Register<HttpClient>();` directly when I test.

> System.ArgumentException: 'For the container to be able to create HttpClient it should have only one public constructor: it has 3

I find a workaround based on using below code:

```
container.Register<HttpClient>(()=>new HttpClient(),Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

based on 
[Registering a type with multiple constructors and string dependency in Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892191/registering-a-type-with-multiple-constructors-and-string-dependency-in-simple-in)

However, I advice that you use the built-in `IHttpClientFactory` in asp.net core:

The `IHttpClientFactory` can be registered by calling the `services.AddHttpClient()` in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#basic-usage

Comment: I agree with Xing Zou, don't inject `HttpClient` directly, but use `IHttpClientFactory`. [This page](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/654) shows how to integrate `IHttpClientFactory` in Simple injector.